# wkhtmltopdf and PDF/A-1b

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I use this software in a .Net project, to convert HTML in PDF.

It work's great for me.

I want to produce files PDF in the format PDF/A-1b.

There's a way to accomplish this task?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use GhostScript to convert the PDF, that wkhtmltopdf gives you, to PDF/A.

Have a look at the following Stackoverflow question for inspiration:

[Stackoverflow - how to use GS to convert PDF to PDF/A or PDF/X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659147/how-to-use-ghostscript-to-convert-pdf-to-pdf-a-or-pdf-x)

Comment: Yep, and here is .NET wrapper for Ghostscript library that he can use: https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/