# Ghostscript won't generate PDF/A with UTF16BE text string detected in DOCINFO - in spite of PDFACompatibilityPolicy saying otherwise

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am trying to convert normal PDF files to PDF/A with this command line:

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

However, I get the message

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: UTF16BE text string detected in DOCINFO cannot be represented in XMP for PDF/A1, reverting to normal PDF output
```

an gs reverts to normal PDF.
Apparently, the message stems from [this code fragment](https://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-cvs.mbox/2018-June/022891.html) of gs, but there we read that the message can occur only when `pdev->PDFACompatibilityPolicy == 0`. My understanding was that the parameter `-sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1` in the command line has the purpose of preventing this.

**Q:** Why does gs behave as if the desired policy were 0 instead of 1? Is there another way to set the policy to 1?

Also, just as it makes me curious:

**Q:** Is there a way to see what kind of strange DOCINFO there is causing the original problem or to prevent it in the first place? Using Acrobat Reader, I cannot see anything "suspicuous" in the file. If it helps: The input.pdf is generated on Window from Word (and I tried even with the UseISO19005-1 setting, which should produce PDF/A to begin with, but the problem occurs anyway).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have put `-sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1`. That, I'm afraid, is incorrect. Ghostscript has two kinds of switches `-s` which deals with string values, and `-d` which deals with numeric and name values (names in PostScript begin with '/').

You've assigned a string value of '1' to the parameter PDFACompatbilityPolicy, which (internally) expects a numeric value. For reasons to do with the fact that these values are required to be accessible from the PostScript environment, we can't flag the type confusion as an error. Instead we leave the **actual** control at its default value of 0.

If you instead set `-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1` I expect you will see the behaviour you expect.

As for seeing the data, without looking at the PDF file I cannot tell. However, if you stop in the debugger at that point and look at p->data you will be able to see what the data is. If you look at `pairs + i` instead of `pairs + i + 1` you will be able to see the key which is associated with the value from the DOCINFO pdfmark.

You won't be able to see anything 'suspicious' by looking at the file in Acrobat, because Acrobat will translate the UTF16BE into whatever your system requires in order to display the text correctly. It may even be that this is ASCII, you can still represent that as UTF16.

If you open the file in a text editor you **may** be able to see the relevant string (note that the BOM in Ghostscript is in octal, so that's 0xFE 0xFF in hexadecimal), provided its not in a compressed object stream.

Comment: Spot on! Now I have to find a way to [address the hundreds of Google finds](https://xkcd.com/386/) that confidently use  `-s` (one of which I pulled my line from). (And from the found sample llines it looked so convincing, as if the underlying meaning were `-dNAME` for *define* a flag and `-sNAME=VAL` for *set* a value)

Answer (score 5):

Examining the source of latest ghostscript (9.50), it seems that the `PDFACompatibilityPolicy` values in this case (see `devices/vector/gdevpdfm.c` around line 1951) set the error-containing behavior as such:

- 0 will revert to normal PDF output (not really what I wanted)
- 1 will discard PDFINFO (even worse)
- 2 will throw an error (even even worse)
- any other value is ignored in the switch and works as a pass-through!

So, in my case, the whole thing was solved simply by setting

```
-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=3
```

Ghostscript does not complain, does not abort PDF/A output, does not discard the PDFINFO, and, most importantly, veraPDF checker still verifies the PDF as perfectly okay.

I'm not commenting on how ugly this solution is, but it works just great. Since all other switch statements just assume compatibility policy `0` if anything above 2 gets passed in, this "shortcut" seems to be an unintended, but very useful bug.

Comment: Please consider my answer i posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699796/6864538

Answer (score 3):

The answer of exa is not quiet correct. Ghostscript will continue its output but the resulting pdf will not conform the veraPDF validator.

At this moment im busy trying to make ghostscript work so i get a valid zugferd invoice pdf. Therefore the PDF needs to be a valid PDF/A-3(a,b or u) file.

**Problem with the Answer**

If you just use `-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=3` verPDF wont validate the PDF.

Instead you should fix the file with right encoding.

In my case the pdf looked like this:

[image: pdf view via notepad(ansi encoded)]

**How to resolve it:**

Create a new file (example "pdfmarks") with this content:

```
[ /Title (Foo Title)
  /Author (Foo Bar)
  /Subject (Foo Bar Subject)
  /Keywords ()
  /ModDate (D:20061204092842)
  /CreationDate (D:20061204092842)
  /Creator (Foo Bar)
  /Producer (Foo Bar)
  /DOCINFO pdfmark
```

(There's no ending square brackets ']')

Run gs like this:

Windows:
`"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/path/to/output.pdf  /path/to/input.pdf /path/to/pdfmarks`

Linux:
`gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/path/to/output.pdf /path/to/input.pdf  /path/to/pdfmarks`

You can either include your stuff or call gs a second time.

I hope i could safe you guys some time with this.

Comment: This looks great! Is there any simple way to automate it? (The pdf I get is from Latex)
Also, how do I use UTF-8 characters in the pdfmarks file? (is it utf-compatible?)

Comment: U want a linux script running those commands? I can provide that.